# Convert date into julian date

Tags: x++

I want to convert todays date into the julian date format . Suppose if the date is 31/12/2011(31st dec 2011) , then the julian date should be 11365(yyddd) .

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is actually how to convert to Julian date. I think Julian date uses different year and month etc... I live in Ethiopia, and we use a Julian calendar, and it will be new year in 4 days time, so day 200ish in gregorian is day 1 in Julian.

Comment: ok . When i googled it , they showed the julian date format was ddyyy, thats y i was trying out to print date in that format.

Comment: that is ordinal date by Wikipedia: "...the interval of time in days and fractions of a day since January 1, 4713..." and "The use of Julian date to refer to the day-of-year ([ordinal date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date "Ordinal date")) is usually considered to be incorrect although it is widely used that way." Julian Date for 31/12/2011 noon is 2455927!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to get the date in yyddd format would be doing some mathematics:

```
date theDate = 31\12\2011;
int  theOrdDate;

;

theOrdDate = 1000 * (year(theDate) mod 100) + dayOfYr(theDate);

// or 

theOrdDate = 1000 * (year(theDate) - 2000) + dayOfYr(theDate);
```

---

EDIT: one possible drawback: this calculation will return only 4 digits if the year is less than 2010.

Answer (score 1):

In AX2012 this task is super easy.

```
str myJulian; 

myJulian = date2Julian(today());
```